# Application scaling by font doesn't seem to work as expected on screen with high resolutions

Tags: c#

I've developed an App that I've pushed to machines within my business. Some of these managers are using old lenovo (1920x1080) laptops and some are using Surface laptops (2256x1504, 2496x1664) and the scaling of the application on the surface laptops is terrible. The controls are tiny, and I've got a `DataGridView` that is just completely unreadable.

I've set the autoscaling to `Font` (after messing with the other options `dpi`, `inherit`) which to my understanding should remedy this as each of these users has their scaling at 150%/200% which should then change the size of the font, therefore changing the size of the form.

What am I missing? And is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You should probably mention which framework you used to create your app.

Comment: Guessing from the description it is Windows Forms which support for high DPI is horrible, but yes, this needs to be clarified.

Comment: @Ray apologies it's Windows Forms